# centre the peak at x=0

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, signals

[image]Right now the rectangle signal is centre on x = 4, how can I make it centre on x = 0

```
def rect(n,T):
 
    a = np.zeros(int((n-T)/2,))
    b = np.ones((T,))
    c= np.zeros(int((n-T)/2,))
    a1 = np.append(a,b)
    a2 = np.append(a1,c)
    return a2

x =rect(11,6)
plt.step(x, 'r')
plt.show()
```

This is so far that I wrote. Appreciate anyone can give the Idea

Answer (score 0):

A method to center the rectangle at `x=0` is to provide x values to `plt.step`. One way to accomplish this is to use [numpy arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and center the x values around 0 by using the length of `a2` returned in the `rects` function

```py
# Changed to y because it will be our y values in plt.step
y = rect(11, 6)

# Add 0.5 so it's centered
x = np.arange(-len(y)/2 + 0.5, len(y)/2 + 0.5)
```

And then plot it using `plt.step` and setting `where` to `mid` (more info in the [plt.step docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html)):

```py
plt.step(x, y, where='mid', color='r')
```

[image: fig_step]

Hope this helps. Here is the full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def rect(n, T):

    a = np.zeros(int((n-T)/2,))
    b = np.ones((T,))
    c = np.zeros(int((n-T)/2,))
    a1 = np.append(a, b)
    a2 = np.append(a1, c)

    return a2

y = rect(11, 6)

# Add 0.5 so it's centered
x = np.arange(-len(y)/2 + 0.5, len(y)/2 + 0.5)
plt.step(x, y, where='mid', color='r')
plt.show()
```